# Usar un array como atributo e inicializarlo

Tags: java, array, atributos

Buenos días estoy realizando un ejercicio, y tras muchas vueltas no soy capaz de hacer lo que me pide:

La información que tiene un polígono regular es:
- Color (solo habrá 4 colores disponibles: NEGRO, VERDE, ROJO y AZUL). El color por defecto será NEGRO.
- No de lados
- Longitud del lado en cm.
- Si está relleno o no

Los objetos polígonoRegular se pueden crear de las siguientes formas:
- Indicando el color y la longitud del lado.
- Indicando solo la longitud del lado (el color será un valor por defecto: NEGRO).
- Sin parámetros.

He llegado a este código, pero estoy bloqueado, falta por implementar método, algunos abstractos, pero me he quedado sin ideas a la hora de poner usar el array de colores y settearlo a negro por defecto.

```
/**
 * DEFINICIÓN DE LA CLASE ABSTRACTA POLIREGULAR
 * ==============================================================================
 * 
 * @author LUIS QUESADA ROMERO
 */

// PAQUETE AL QUE PERTENECE
package modelos;

public class PoliRegular { // INICIO DE LA CLASE PRINCIPAL POLIREGULAR

    // ATRIBUTOS DE CLASE //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private int nLados;
    private double lLado;
    private boolean relleno;
    private String color = colores[i];

    private final String[] colores = {"NEGRO", "VERDE", "ROJO", "AZUL"};

    public PoliRegular(double lLado, String[] color) {
        this.lLado = lLado;
        this.color = color;
    }



} // FIN DE LA CLASE PRINCIPAL
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes darle un valor por defecto al inicializar la clase. Y además puedes sobrecargar constructores ([aquí tienes un ejemplo por si te ayuda](https://www.abrirllave.com/java/sobrecarga-de-metodos-y-constructores.php)). Quiere decir que tienes varios constructores definidos, y dependiendo de los parámetros con los que se llama al constructor se usará uno u otro.

A ti te valdría algo así:

```
package modelos;

public class PoliRegular {
    private int nLados;
    private double lLado;
    private boolean relleno;
    private final String[] colores = {"NEGRO", "VERDE", "ROJO", "AZUL"};
    private String color = colores[0]; // Así escogemos color "NEGRO" por defecto.

    // Define longitud de lado y color del polígono.
    PoliRegular(double lLado, int colorIndice) {
        this.lLado = lLado;
        this.color = colores[colorIndice];
    }

    PoliRegular(double lLado) {
        this.lLado = lLado;
    }
}
```

Si no das un valor por defecto al principio, el segundo constructor podría ser así:

```
PoliRegular(double lLado) {
    this(lLado, 0); // Llamada al primer constructor con el indice del color por defecto.
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, en principio me obligan en ejercicio a usar un array con los cuatro colores permitidos, por eso mi intención era sacar una variable color y asignarle colores[i], esa era mi idea, porque no se como usar ni majenar ese array de los cuatro colores.

Comment: @LuisQuesadaRomero he actualizado mi respuesta, creo que ahora te valdrá mejor.

Comment: colorIndice, supongo que es el indice del array colores 0,1,2,3?

Comment: Sí. Si un polígono de lados tamaño 3cm es negro sería: `new PoliRegular(3, 0);`, si es verde: `new PoliRegular(3, 1);`, si es rojo: `new PoliRegular(3, 2);` y si es azul: `new PoliRegular(3, 3);`.